# Query executed via JdbcTemplate not rolled back, even though via CrudRepository it is

Tags: spring-boot, db2, jdbctemplate, rollback, crud-repository

I have a Spring Boot project with a test case that calls a public method `deleteEntity(Long id)` on a service. The method is annotated with `@Transactional` and it should delete an entity with the given id, after which it throws a RuntimeException to induce a rollback.

If I implement `deleteEntity(Long id)` by using `JdbcTemplate`, the rollback occurs (logs confirm this) but it is not reflected in my database. If I implement it by using a `CrudRepository`, it works fine.

This is the code for the service that is called in the test case (`JdbcTemplate` code is commented out) :

```
@Service
public class TransactionalAPI {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private QueueEntryDAO dao;

    @Transactional
    public void deleteEntity(Long entryID) {
        dao.deleteById(entryID);
        throw new RuntimeException("Fake exception for testing purposes.");
//        int rows = template.update(String.format("DELETE FROM MYSCHEMA.BATCH_QUEUE WHERE ID = %d", entryID));
//        System.out.printf("Deleted %d rows.", rows);
//        throw new RuntimeException("Fake exception for testing purposes.");
    }

}
```

My database is an IBM DB2 database. Creating a minimal working example may be useful except that it's in-house code and I don't have administrator access to the database. That's why I wrote this test case as a replacement (the real problem I'm trying to solve is that I'm trying to clean up the Spring Batch tables and I'm having issues making that code transactional).

I looked at internals of `SimpleJPARepository` to try and spot the differences compared to `JdbcTemplate` and it's telling the entity manager to remove the entity, but the code is quite involved so it's hard to compare. Any idea what could be happening here?